# Conversions in GA stopped being attributed to UTMs when we switched to Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, utm

Previously, we had implemented Traditional e-commerce analytics (_gaq) using _trackTrans, _addItem, etc. We had several years of data in GA that correlated conversions with our Ad campaigns, based on UTM source, campaign, medium.

When switching over to Google Tag Manager, we did the following things:
• Removed the _gaq code related to e-commerce (transactions & addItem)
• Kept the rest of the GA code related to page tracking, events, and custom variables
• Implemented the Google Tag Manager javascript + a GTM data layer that included our new E-commerce information (Google Tag Manager data layer)

• Configured a "Tag" in GTM for "Order Completed" for Google Analytics, set to Universal Analytics (Configured with our UA- property identifier, etc.). Tag type= Universal Analytics; Tracking ID= our GA environment, Track Type = "Page View" , Enable enhanced e-commerce feature = true, Use data layer = True; Fire on "Order completed"

Upon switching over, we indeed see E-commerce numbers come through, but there's something off about the recording of these conversions correctly back to the campaigns. It appears that while some are attributed back, not all conversions are counted correctly as being from the ad campaign they originated from.

What went wrong here? After thorough reading of the GTM documentation, we were led to believe that it would "just work" but it appears that GTM and GA don't know how to communicate with each other regarding UTM information, and as a result GA tracks conversions but fails to attribute them to right session (that is, ITS session information that contains the correct UTM for that user).

We found a very scant amount of information about this on the internet-- but some people suggest setting all the UTMs are "Variables" in GTM, and then passing them as fields in the Tag firing back to GA. Is that necessary? It seems like these two technologies should work together with less friction.

Please advise.

Comment: The combination of GA and GTM does indees "just work" (unless you specifically override the "location" field which would strip the parameters), the problem must be elsewhere. Check your referral exclusion list to make sure that your own domain and all external payment gateways are listed there, then make sure you don't have any redirects on your landingpages that forget to forward the utm parameters or click id.

Comment: Thank you this is interesting. When you say "referral exclusion list" what product are you referring to, GTM or GA?  As far as external payment gateways we use server-side payment gateways only. RE: Redirects--- we do actually have some redirects that I just now realized may not be forwarding query params correctly. However, please note: GA is picking up UTMs fine, just not attributing the conversion to them. If wiped-out query params were the problem, seems like GA wouldn't see those UTMs in the first place

Comment: Wrong attributions happen either when the client changes the marketing channel (which is why I suggested to check the referral exclusions) or when the session is interrupted and restarted with a different client id. Do you by chance have a setup where both GTM and GA code are used ? Maybe you accidentally create multiple trackers (to check set page depth as secondary dimension on your transaction report to see if it's unusally low for the misattributed visits).

Comment: We definitely implemented both GTM and GA code (Universal Analytics), as per the documentation. The GA code sends pageviews, custom dimensions, and events. The GTM dataLayer sends add-to-cart and transaction (completed purchase). So the two systems do not send the same information. The only hook between them is the Tag (explained above), which pushes transaction information from GTM into GA.